# How to add same value with help of update query using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have records on my table and I have to update the records.if records are available then add the same value which is already in a database.

For example: I have column name aMan and value is 30 so I have to update same value and new values will be 60.

```
//Total column value=column value + column value 

if ($check_record >0) { 
    // will check the records available or not
    $sql="UPDATE man SET aMan = '$action_points' where user_id='$id'";
} else {
    $new=$column_value + $column_value;
    $sql="UPDATE man SET aMan = '$new' where user_id='$id'";
}
```

In short I have to add the value.Would you help me in this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  following will double the `aMan` value:

```
$sql = "UPDATE man SET aMan=aMan*2 WHERE user_id='$id'";
```

If you only need to add a specific value and not the same value as the column already has, use:

```
$sql = "UPDATE man SET aMan=aMan+30 WHERE user_id='$id'";
```

If you need to update multiple columns at the same time, use something like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE man SET aMan=aMan+30, bMan=bMan+20 WHERE user_id='$id'";
```

Also, I suggest you to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of adding an `$id` variable diretly into your query string, which is very unsafe.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Yury, In case i have to update every time 30 than what qyery i have to use it?

Comment: Where should I use that query inside if or else?

Comment: Inside your `else` statement, instead of both lines

Comment: Mr.Yury, I have one more doubt.In case there are more than on column then what will be update query i have to use it?

Comment: I don't know Mr.Yury, I am getting lots of doubt now.

Comment: Mr.Yury, Your query help me 90% but i have some doubt.

Comment: Cool! my issue got resolved now. Thanks for your help Mr.Yury.Upvote from my side

Answer (score 0):

This can be a another approach.

```
$sql="UPDATE man SET aMan = aMan + aMan where user_id='$id'";
```